# Why does "hostname -d" gives different output than domainname?

Tags: samba, hostname, join, samba4

I have joined an Ubuntu 14.04 machine to domain using samba 4 but auth is not working. Look what I get:

```
# net ads keytab create -U 'admin'
Enter admin's password:
ads_get_dnshostname: No dNSHostName attribute!
../source3/libads/kerberos_keytab.c:328: unable to determine machine account's dns name in AD!
```

Testing if my FQDN is correct I get:

```
# hostname -d
dom.forest.int

# domainname
(none)
```

Why does *domainname* has different behavior than *hostname -d*? Could this be the problem with Samba?

This is my configuration:

```
# grep MYPCNAME /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1       MYPCNAME.dom.forest.int MYPCNAME
```

and this:

```
# cat /etc/hostname
MYPCNAME
```

Is my configuration correct? How can I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: if your Host is in Domain u don't need to assign a hostname by manually it will be provided by DNS

Answer (score 0):

You got different answer bacouse `hostaname` give you "name before domain". Command `hostname -d` give you domain aka `DNS domain name`.

Your full hostname you will got with command `hostname -f`

On some way can say `hostname` + `hostname -d` = `hostname -f`

Comment: Yes I know that, but why does *domainname* prints *(none)*? Does it have a different configuration that hostname? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use "dnsdomainname", not "domainname":

`domainname - show or set system's NIS/YP domain name
...
dnsdomainname - show the system's DNS domain name`

Source: HOSTNAME(1) ("man domainname")

Answer (score 0):

The **manpage** explains this quite clearly. Quoting from [`man hostname`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/hostname.1):

```
-d, --domain
                  Display  the  name  of the DNS domain. Don't use the command domainname to get the DNS domain name because it will show the NIS domain name and not the DNS domain name. Use dnsdomainname instead.
```

So `domainname` will show the NIS domain name, you need to use `dnsdomainname` instead.